enable the strict mode in development with vite and vue3
I am working on vue3 and vite,
running npm run dev gives no errors
but running  npm run build gives a lot of more errors, I know it is because of the strict mode in tsconfig.
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "strict": true,

My questions is how could I enable the strict mode in the development mode so I can find the errors in advance ?

Don't you have it in your IDE? problems in VScode. Look alongside ESlint if you use that tool too.
